# Playing Sound from an array by image button in case?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I want to create an app that plays a song randomly from an array.
I created 4 image buttons and each button plays a random song from my array when clicked.
How would I play a song randomly from an array when image button is clicked?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    int[] soundbr = {
            R.raw.b1, R.raw.b2, R.raw.b3, R.raw.b4, R.raw.b4, R.raw.b5, R.raw.b6,
            R.raw.b7, R.raw.b8, R.raw.b9, R.raw.b10, R.raw.b11, R.raw.b12
    };
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageButton imageButton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1); //button for happy
        imageButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
        ImageButton imagebutton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);//button for brokenhearted
        imagebutton2.setOnClickListener(this);
        ImageButton imagebutton3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);//button for inspired
        imagebutton3.setOnClickListener(this);
        ImageButton imagebutton4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);//button for inlove
        imagebutton4.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.imageButton2:
                //play a music here
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to play device music files or the one in your assets folder?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't "do my work for me" Try some stuff out, do some research.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play the audio file just declare the media player and pass the data source to it which will be the array now you can wrap following code in loop so that every time you stop the sound and play again the next sound will be played.

```
 myPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        myPlayer.setLooping(false);
        myPlayer.setDataSource(youdatasource);
        myPlayer.prepare();
        myPlayer.start();
```

And while stopping you should write this code in you image button listener.

```
        myPlayer.stop();
        myPlayer.release();
```